# publishing Picasa web albums on a web site

Tags: joomla2.5, picasa

I am little confused with how to publish my Picasa web album on my Joomla web site.  I created a web album using my Picasa program and now I need to publish on a Joomla web page.  Some articles says use your FTP client to upload the album to the server.  How can I do so,  Where to upload my album,  how it get shown on a web article?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of extensions that allow you to embed Picasa albums in your Joomla articles. Many are even free.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/photo-channels/google-images

Comment: aren't all they about web albums created online?? I meant a web gallery created using installed Picasa application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Most of the extensions at the link are designed to display Picasa web albums in a Joomla site.